# Less mileage and bumpy ride in VW polo after shocks and timing belt replacement

Tags: vw, suspension, timing-belt, shock-absorber, power-loss

I own a VW Polo TDI, 2011. I recently had all four shocks replaced. I also got my timing belt and fan belt replaced. I also did the alignment afterwards. I have made a few observations which I would like experts to comment on:

1. Earlier my car used to stick to road while I accelerated and I did not feel the speed that I am on. The ride would be very smooth at least till 100kmph. But now I feel the car accelerating. it seems engine needs more effort to reach that speed.
2. Though my ride quality is improved, but I feel that my car is more sensitive towards the irregularities in the road. I would bounce more often.
3. Less power in lower revs. The places where 3rd gear would be sufficient now require 2nd.
4. Loss in mileage. I have at least lost 1-1.5 km per liter in my last tank.

Are those things normal?

Comment: Is the timing precise? diesels are very intolerant to errors on timing - even half a tooth can cause excessive smoke (had this on a Perkins 4203 engine...), will affect power output and consumption as well. For the ride, why did you change the shocks? where they completely useless or you felt that a new set was a good idea? Have you checked the tyre pressures? Did the front/rear wheels get mixed up?

Comment: @Solar Mike. Thanks for the quick response. I changed the shocks because they were worn out and leaking. They were not completely useless, but still required change. I keep tire pressure close to 30 psi. How do I check for the timing? I got it replaced by my mechanic. Its a timing belt and not a chain. Can a belt be off tooth as well?

Comment: Are all tyres the same pressure ? should there be a difference front / rear? Timing belts can be off as well, but if you had it done by a mechanic, then take it back and explain the issues you are having. There are marks on engines that need to be aligned when doing this work.

Comment: All tyres are same air pressure. Specifications suggest to be 34 rear and 31 front. I never bothered with that earlier and the drive was fine. I just rode around 500 kms. The drive seems to be fine now. Mileage is not as good as it was earlier, but not bad either. Does engine take some miles to get accustomed to the new equipment?